# How to display the time with half and hour intervals in sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008, I have time column (`varchar`) with time intervals 10 min basis. I want to display the time with half and hour basis..

The table (`timeslot`) has this data:

```
time
-----
11:10 AM
11:20 AM
11:30 AM
11:40 AM
11:50 AM
12:00 PM
12:10 PM
12:20 PM
12:30 PM
12:40 PM
12:50 PM
01:00 PM
01:10 PM
01:20 PM
```

And I want to display this output:

```
time
-----
11:00 AM
11:30 AM
12:00 PM
12:30 PM
01:00 PM
01:30 PM
```

Can anybody help me on this? thanks in advance...

Comment: Time stored as varchar? **WHY?!?!?** - use the appropriate data type - `TIME` !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    (list of columns)
FROM 
    dbo.YourTableWithTheTime
WHERE 
    DATEPART(MINUTE, CAST(YourTimeColumnHere as TIME)) IN (0, 30)
```

Of course - if you used the **appropriate** datatype of `TIME` for your column in the first place, you could save yourself the `CAST(.. as TIME)` construct and things would be even easier....

**Update:** if you need to order by your time - use this:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT [time]
FROM 
    dbo.YourTableWithTheTime
WHERE 
    DATEPART(MINUTE, CAST([time] as TIME)) IN (0, 30)
ORDER BY
    CAST([time] as TIME)
```

PS: it's also a *really bad idea* to name a column `time` - since that's a reserved keyword (for the datatype) in SQL Server 2008 .....

Comment: Thank you!very much dear but still i am getting each row getting twice. if i add distinct or group by option, i will get correct answer. but not in order of time that column starts with 01:oo PM i want to start with 11:00 AM.

Comment: You need to CAST your column as TIME in your column select before you ORDER BY this column

Comment: @user1740091: check my updated response - that should work just fine.

Comment: still getting twice each row or each time

Comment: database table have twice each time. now i want unique values pls help on this...?

Comment: @user1740091: use the `DISTINCT` keyword in the `SELECT` to get unique values only ... see my updated response .

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE 
AS (SELECT DISTINCT columnname FROM table_name
WHERE DATEPART(MINUTE, CAST(column as TIME)) IN (0, 30) )
SELECT columnname
FROM CTE
ORDER BY CAST(columnname as time)
```